# Get parent and child rows

Tags: php

I am want to loop through the parent and get the child for each $_POST['start_time_uuid'], I can't seem to get the right child for each parent.

```
$max = sizeof($_POST['start_time_uuid']);
for ($x=0;$x<$max;$x++){
    $soa = sizeof($_POST['start_time']);
    for ($i=0; $i < $soa;$i++){

        $start_time = $_POST['start_time'][$i];
        $end_time = $_POST['end_time'][$i];

        $fieldsVals = array(
        'start_time' => $start_time,
        'end_time' => $end_time
        );
    }

    $where = array('uuid' => $_POST['start_time_uuid'][$x]);
    $disregard = $PDO->sql_update($fieldsVals, $table, $where);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure of the relationship between the question and the code pasted here. I would not normally expect something called `$PDO->sql_update` to print anything at all, and I cannot see any other output going on in the code provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$max = sizeof($_POST['start_time_uuid']);
for ($x=0;$x<$max;$x++){
    $soa = sizeof($_POST['start_time']);
    for ($i=0; $i < $soa;$i++){

        $start_time = $_POST['start_time'][$i];
        $end_time = $_POST['end_time'][$i];

        $fieldsVals[$x]['start_time'] = $start_time;
        $fieldsVals[$x]['end_time'] = $end_time;
    }

    $where = array('uuid' => $_POST['start_time_uuid'][$x]);
    $disregard = $PDO->sql_update($fieldsVals, $table, $where);
}
```

With your code here:

```
    $fieldsVals = array(
        'start_time' => $start_time,
        'end_time' => $end_time
    );
```

You seem to overwrite the previous array with just another 2 element array.
If you make it a multidimensional array you will be able to save the data needed.
Hope this is what you meant and that this helps